# Django queries based on amount of many to many relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have `Film` and `Person` models that have many to many relationships, since each film can contain many actors/actresses, and each actor/actress can be in many films.

I'm wondering if there's a way to limit a query based on how many films an actor has.

For example,

```
Person.objects.all()
```

will return everyone in the database, while

```
Person.objects.all()[0].film_set.all()
```

Will return a set of all films that include the first person in the database.

I'm wondering if it's possible to say, query all the `Person` objects that have at least 10 films in their `film_set`.

I know one way is to just query all the Person objects and then an if statement of if `len(film_set.all()) > n` looping through them and make a sublist out of that, but is there a better way that doesn't involve iterating through the entire database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

```
from django.db.models import Count
people = Person.objects.all().annotate(film_count=Count('film')).filter(film_count__gte=10)
```